Restrict AgGrid pivot grid autoupdate functionality
I am working on a react application and there I have a below requirement.
In aggrid pivot, when i add or checked a checkbox of column then the pivot grid should not get updated immediately. I have a button to update that one. Also when checking a checkbox i want to store the values in a object, similar way for removing or adding rowgroup and pivotgroup as well, i did lot of research but did not get a solution on this.
Can someone please help me with this.
